# Translating for websites - English to Chinese (Simplified) - Characters or written?

Tags: internationalization, vue-i18n

My question is this:

Should Chinese characters be used or should the translations be spelled out?

delete > 删除

or

delete > Shānchú

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test your translated website with users of the destination language, and use the terms and spelling which they prefer. You should have a translator who is skilled in the source and destination language perform the translation, and accept the terms and spelling which they suggest.

I am not a user of websites in Chinese, nor a translator. But from what I understand of the language, Chinese should certainly be written in characters (e.g. 删除). The Latin script spelling (Shānchú) is used by those who do not read the Chinese script, as a way to understand the sound of the words.

Comment: Thanks Jim, good answers, and given the proper resources that is what I would have done...